# Error building on npm

Tags: npm

I'm having the following error when running 'npm run build' for my  app.

```
⠋ building for production.../home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:170
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap(
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
    at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.apply (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:170:20)
    at Compiler.apply (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:33:19)
    at err (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/build/build.js:19:3)
    at next (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:75:7)
    at CB (/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:111:9)
    at /home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:137:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! musixshare@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the musixshare@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/edu/.npm/_logs/2018-05-25T17_24_14_199Z-debug.log
```

And this is the error log I got:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~prebuild: musixshare@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: musixshare@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare/node_modules/.bin:/home/edu/bin:/home/edu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: CWD: /home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare
10 silly lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'node build/build.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle musixshare@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: musixshare@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid musixshare@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/edu/Dropbox/projects/personal/for good/musixshare
16 verbose Linux 4.13.0-43-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error musixshare@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the musixshare@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How can I solve this? I can run 'npm run dev' normally, just the build return this error. I've already tried updating all the dependencies.

Comment: Not enough info. The problem appears to be coming from last-call-webpack-plugin.

Comment: What kind of info should i give?

Comment: Anything helps. There's very little here about what your app actually is/does. A good starting point would be the contents of your `webpack.config.js` as it looks like your build script is in webpack.

Comment: Yes, the error is in last-call-webpack-plugin, maybe a downgrade would fix it?

Comment: Added the full error code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the solution, the problem was a incompatibility between webpack and optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin. Downgrading the package to v3.2.0 got it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post this. It helped me too. For my curiosity, what type of js framework are you using? React Vue Angular? I'm using Vue Typescript with Bootstrap Vue 2.0.0 (rc 28). I also updated all my dependencies and it didn't help either.